# OpenCV Adaboost: "The function/feature is not implemented"

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, classification, adaboost

I have feature vectors of some objects from two classes and my goal is to train a boosted classifier with this information. After looking at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html) and the letter recognition example I thought it would be straight forward to do so, but for some reason I get the following error when training the classifier:

> OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Boosted trees can only be used for 2-class classification.)

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
Mat X = Mat::zeros(train_size, feat_size, CV_32F);
Mat Y = Mat::zeros(train_size, 1, CV_32S);

// filling of X with the corresponding features for each training sample
// filling of Y with labels 1 and -1 depending on the class

CvBoostParams params(CvBoost::DISCRETE, 100, 0.95, 1, false, 0);
Mat var_type = Mat(feat_size+1, 1, CV_8U, Scalar::all(CV_VAR_ORDERED));
var_type.ptr<uchar>(feat_size)[1] = CV_VAR_CATEGORICAL;

CvBoost boost;
boost.train(X, CV_ROW_SAMPLE, Y, Mat(), Mat(), var_type, Mat(), params);
```

I think the problem here is the var_type Mat. As far as I understand it has to contain one entry per feature plus one entry for the response. Since my feature are all numerical measurements I set the first elements to CV_VAR_ORDERED and the last element to CV_VAR_CATEGORICAL.

Can anybody explain to me why OpenCV things this is not a 2-class classification?

Another thing: For the predictions I don't want the actual predicted labels but the probability of belonging to class 1. This actually wouldn't be hard to compute if I could get the sum of weighted votes. The predict method has a flag **returnSum** but the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html#cvboost-predict) says: *If true then return sum of votes instead of the class label.* Do they really mean sum of votes or sum of weighted votes?